# Rails 3.1 and Image Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have put all my images for my admin theme in the assets folder within a folder called admin. Then I link to it like normal ie.

```
# Ruby    
image_tag "admin/file.jpg" .....
#CSS
.logo{ background:url('/assets/images/admin/logo.png');
```

FYI. Just for testing I am not using the asset_path tag just yet as I have not compiled my assets.

Ok all good so far until I decided to update an image. I replaced some colors but on reload the new styled image is not showing. If I view the image directly in the browser its still showing the old image. Going one step further I destroyed the admin images folder. But it has broken nothing all the images are still being displayed.  And yes I have cleared my cache and have tried on multiple browsers.

Is there some sort of image caching going on?  This is just local development using pow to serve the pages.

Even destroying the whole images folder the images are still being served.

Am I missing something?

Comment: that's not the case with 3.1 using the asset pipeline. You would use the command rake assets:precompile which will compress those files and move them to the public file

Comment: Well moving them to the public folder worked, all a bit strange as they worked fine being served from the assets folder. Maybe have to wait for more docs on 3.1.

Comment: I understand your frustration. Apparently release candidates don't get documented very well.

Comment: Leave them in assets, just don't include a folder path at all. See my answer below.

Answer (score 226):

In 3.1 you just get rid of the 'images' part of the path. So an image that lives in `/assets/images/example.png` will actually be accessible in a get request at this url - `/assets/example.png`

Because the `assets/images` folder gets generated along with a new 3.1 app, this is the convention that they probably want you to follow. I think that's where `image_tag` will look for it, but I haven't tested that yet.

Also, during the RailsConf keynote, I remember D2h saying the the `public folder` should not have much in it anymore, mostly just error pages and a favicon.

Comment: Yea I have played with this allot and they have some way to go to make it easier.  Yes putting them in my assets folder works but then you can use the assets tag. So I am waiting to see what more info comes out.

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot, too. This is the kind of stuff that's driving me crazy as a dude trying to learn Rails having come from other web development frameworks.

Comment: and what would happen if two different folders contained the same filename ?

Comment: Not sure why they had to change something that already worked.

Answer (score 98):

You'll want to change the extension of your css file from `.css.scss` to `.css.scss.erb` and do:

```
background-image:url(<%=asset_path "admin/logo.png"%>);
```

You may need to do a "hard refresh" to see changes. CMD+SHIFT+R on OSX browsers.

In production, make sure

```
rm -rf public/assets    
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

happens upon deployment.

Comment: There are new image helpers in sass: image_url, image_path,...
More can be found here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

No need to use erb as a preprocessor anymore

Comment: I tried the sass-rails helpers (image_url and image-url) into a css.scss file but it does not seems to be interpreted. Any clue ?

Comment: @invaino Do you have sass-rails instead of just sass in your Gemfile?

Comment: @user288024 not the case in any versions of 3.1 I've used, but 3.1 has undergone many changes since the time of this posting.

Comment: @user288024 could you give a concrete example? I don't see any problems so far

Comment: The generated scss files are named .css.scss by default, no shitting of the bed has happened yet

Comment: For some reason image-url didn't work for me, but asset-url('myimage.png', image) worked perfectly. (Rails 3.1)

Comment: In case anyone upgrading from 3.0 is wondering, you can just rename your stylesheets from `.css` to `.css.erb` (after you've moved them into `app/assets` to get the erb processing without sass.

Comment: it's working though i prefer writing Pure CSS only withouht embedding other languages .

Answer (score 22):

For what it's worth, when I did this I found that no folder should be include in the path in the css file. For instance if I have `app/assets/images/example.png`, and I put this in my css file...

```
div.example { background: url('example.png'); }
```

... then somehow it magically works. I figured this out by running the `rake assets:precompile` task, which just sucks everything out of all your load paths and dumps it in a junk drawer folder: `public/assets`. That's ironic, IMO...

In any case this means you don't need to put any folder paths, everything in your assets folders will all end up living in one huge directory. How this system resolves file name conflicts is unclear, you may need to be careful about that.

Kind of frustrating there aren't better docs out there for this big of a change.

Comment: When there are naming conflicts, the first path that appears in the config.assets.paths array is the file that is chosen. This can be avoided by using the `asset_path()` helper and specifying the directory.

Comment: This "magically works" because the css file and the images are in the same location.  CSS file references are relative to the location of the css file.

Comment: The asset pipeline can be a bit of a black box, especially for front-end developers, but it offers a lot of great features like not having to worry about file paths and automatic cache busting.

Answer (score 16):

In rails 4 you can now use a css and sass helper image-url:

```
div.logo {background-image: image-url("logo.png");}
```

If your background images aren't showing up consider looking at how you're referencing them in your stylesheets.

Comment: This is correct (for rails 4). Vote this answer up!

Comment: Rails 'helps you out' by putting in the url keyword as well as the string. This means that you can do things like. `div.logo {background: image-url("logo.png") no-repeat center;}`

Answer (score 10):

when referencing images in CSS or in an IMG tag, use image-name.jpg

while the image is really located under ./assets/images/image-name.jpg

Comment: I think this is wrong when it comes to CSS - using rails 3.1.0.rc4 when I use `background: url('sort_asc_disabled.png')` it works for the file app/assets/images/sort_asc_disabled.png.

Answer (score 2):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline

This railscast (Rails Tutorial video on asset pipeline) helps a lot to explain the paths in assets pipeline as well. I found it pretty useful, and actually watched it a few times.

The solution I chose is @Lee McAlilly's above, but this railscast helped me to understand why it works. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The asset pipeline in rails offers a method for this exact thing.

You simply add image_path('image filename') to your css or scss file and rails takes care of everything. For example:

`.logo{ background:url(image_path('admin/logo.png'));`

*(note that it works just like in a .erb view, and you don't use "/assets" or "/assets/images" in the path)*

Rails also offers other helper methods, and there's another answer here: [How do I use reference images in Sass when using Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393315/how-do-i-use-reference-images-in-sass-when-using-rails-3-1)

Comment: I know this question is a couple years old, but this was the first page I found on google when searching for this, so it would be awesome to select an answer so others can easily reference this!