# Image background url from admin directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I have image `1.png` inside assets admin folder.

Full path `/myapp/app/assets/images/admin/1.png`

when im trying to do it

```
body { background: url(admin/1.png) }
```

It doesn't work

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393315/how-do-i-use-reference-images-in-sass-when-using-rails-3-1

Comment: Check `background-image: url("/assets/admin/1.png")`