# missing fingerprints in asset paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

We just deployed a Rails 3.1 app using the new asset pipeline. In Development everything looks fine, but in production all asset-images are missing.
When deploying we followed the Ruby on Rails Edge Guide. As an example, a simple code snippet from our app:

```
asset_path "favicon.png", "images"
```

This generates in production:

```
/assets/favicon.png
```

But the fingerprint is missing (and therefore it is a deadlink on production). We already tried it without the "images", with `image_tag` instead. Nothing is working.

*Additional Information:*

- Rails Version 3.1.0

*Already looked at and tried:*

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1209
- [Rails 3.1 and Image Assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213218/rails-3-1-and-image-assets)
- [Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline and Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683584/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-and-caching)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recent [Railscast Episode #282](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1) covered switching assets from 3.0 to 3.1 with asset pipeline. Have you already tried setting `config.assets.digest = true` in config/environments/production.rb?