# Rails 3.1 using images under app/assets/images/subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my Rails 3.1 app, I have images stored under `app/assets/images/jquery_ui/`.

I don't know how to access these in my CSS. `/assets/image_name.png` and `/assets/jquery_ui/image_name.png` do not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like  /assets/jquery_ui/image_name.png should work,

See [the answers here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213218/rails-3-1-and-image-assets)

Comment: No, I mentioned in the original question that it doesn't work. I don't see why not though...

Comment: Is it just css that can't find them?  Can you get them in a regular http request on your server?  i.e. http://localhost:8888/assets/jquery_ui/image_name.png (or whatever)?

Comment: It turned out that the image not being displayed had nothing to do with the path `(/assets/jquery_ui/image.png)` was right. It was just a stupid mistake where I named the image wrong.

Comment: Did not worked for me, but `/assets/images/jquery_ui/image_name.png` worked instead (Rails 3.2.8)

Answer (score 0):

If you just added some images to assets and it still doesn't work... you will need to restart your server (/WEBrick).