# Ruby on Rails displaying image with image_tag src

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I have an image in my `app/assets/images` folder and I'm in my view page trying to display an image.

```
<%= image_tag "NoAvatar.png" %>
```

When I load my page in localhost my image only shows `/assets/` in its src path

```
<img alt="Assets" src="/assets/">
```

I'm not understanding why this is the issue? Am I doing something wrong? I thought this was how its supposed to link to an image in your pipeline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If your image is in assets, use:

```
<%= image_tag("entretien.jpg", width: 200) %>
```

Answer (score 5):

rails 3.1 n later have a new feature called 'asset pipeline', u can read it at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

u can access the image in the view as

```
= image_tag "/assets/large/icon.png"
```

the image 'icon.png' resides in 'large' under 'images' in 'assets'

to see how to refer the same image in css, see [Rails 3.1 and Image Assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213218/rails-3-1-and-image-assets)

Comment: I don't understand how this is not the same thing as what I have?

Comment: u have to specify the full path of the image. if not provided, it assumes that the image is in 'assets/images'.

Comment: Which it is, if you read my post it is in `app/assets/images/`