# Images not showing for deployed app in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The images that I am using in my index.html.erb file are in the assets/images directory. I have deployed the app to heroku but it is not showing the images. I am linking the images using  tag in the html file and not in the css file.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3.1 and Image Assets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213218/rails-3-1-and-image-assets)

Comment: Post some snippets from your erb file as well as the output in the browser and server consoles.

Comment: Have you double checked your [configuration files](http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/02/untangling-the-rails-asset-pipeline-part-3-configuration/) ?

Comment: Got a link we could look at?

Answer (score 3):

If your images are part of your asset pipeline (I.E `assets/images`), you should be able to access them relatively simply with Heroku, especially if you're using `image_tag` to do this (rather than `css`)

--

**Precompile**

Since [Heroku relies on your assets being static (`precompiled`),](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#rails-asset-pipeline) I would make sure the assets are precompiled on the system, and that you're referencing them correctly:

```
#cmd
$ heroku run rake assets:precompile
```

This will precompile the assets on Heroku's system (which should have been done anyway), ensuring your app should be able to access the files correctly. This is the first thing to test, as it's often the case the files will remain non-compiled, preventing Heroku from reading them

--

**Images**

In reference to your images, you need to know from the [`asset pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) that calling `image_tag "your_image.png` *should* automatically call `assets/images`, `vendor/assets/images` and `public/assets/images` to pull the correct file

If this works in local, it means your paths are okay. If it does not work in local, it means your paths are incorrect, and the issue will be with your code.

---

You should provide a link to your Heroku app *and* show us the HTML / erb files you're using

Answer (score 1):

If your images are indeed in that folder then you can use this method here [How to reference images in CSS within Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257555/how-to-reference-images-in-css-within-rails-4)

But if your uploading images into your Rails app via Carrierwave then you need to use an external image hosting provider such as Cloudinary.  This is because the Heroku environment is refreshed each git push so any files on the server that were uploaded, since they're not on the client git side, are removed.

You can run `heroku run bash` to look around your directories on Heroku to verify if the image is there.

**EDIT**

In regular views you can access images in the public/assets/images directory like this:

```
<%= image_tag "rails.png" %>
```

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Comment: You see the problem is: My images are not refernced in stylesheet that is inside CSS files. I have referenced them inside HTML files and I need to keep it that way, so given that how do I make the images appear after deploying to heroku